# HTML5 - Show Items Side By Side

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS so I am creating a simple website to learn how it works.

I have a header that contains the website name and a collection of links. I'd like to format it so that they are side by side. (Similar to StackExchange, as seen above. The website name to the left, links to the right).

I've included my current markup below but it doesn't appear to be doing anything. I suspect I'm using CSS classes and subclasses incorrectly or I have the concept wrong. Can someone point out any errors I might have made or point me to a resource for further reference? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I want the website name above the the slogan, to the right and the links to the left.

**CSS**

```
header 
{
    clear:both;
}

header .section 
{
    float:left;
}

header .nav 
{
    float:right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
        <section>
            <h1>My Website</h1>
            <p>My Slogan</p>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Link A</a> | 
            <a href="#">Link B</a>
        </nav>
</header>
<article>
    My website contents
</artcile>
```

**Answered**

There were multiple correct answers but I can unfortunately only mark one as correct. 
The correct answer was to remove the dots in ".section" and ".nav" as well as to set the header to overflow:auto rather than clear:both. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You would use `header` and not `.header` for example. The dot means it's an element with that class name. Without the dot, it selects elements with that *tag* name.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. I updated my code and removed the dots from the CSS. That appears to have done the trick but now my article is being formatted with the side by side as well.

Comment: @Dragonseer You'll need to remove the dot in front of the other tag names as well (`section`, `nav`) in your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this, right?

```
header {
    overflow:auto;
}

header section {
    float:left;
}
header nav {
    float:right; /* or left */
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hFqaz/1/)

As mentioned in the comments, you use `header` as opposed to `.header`, `section` as opposed to `.section`, `nav` instead of `.nav`.

The `.` is used to reference classes.

`overflow:auto` will make the parent contain the child, since a height isn't set on it.

Comment: That appears to have done the trick. I'm a little confused however since my web searches show everyone using clear:both, rather than overflow:auto.

Comment: Josh - clear:both doesn't appear to be working at all for me, but overflow:auto works great.

Comment: @Dragonseer Glad that helped! If you have anymore questions, let me know!

Answer (score 3):

One easy way would be to add this rule:

```
nav {
    float:right;
}
section {
    float:left;
}
section h1 {
    margin:0;
}
article {
    clear:both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mruLz/2/)**

This makes all the elements within the header display inline and appear side by side.

Comment: He's going for *"website name to the left, links to the right"*

Comment: I should clarify: I want the website name above the the slogan, to the right and the links to the left.

Comment: Oooooh, totally mis-read that. Wait, are the links to the left or right?

Comment: @Dragonseer - Yup, I assumed that based on your other comments. My answer shows my changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/pk5ER/)

```
header {
  height: 50px;
}
header section {
  float:left;
}
header nav {
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mdesdev. That appears to have done the trick to get stuff to format. However, now my article with my Lipsum text is being formatted as well and being pulled next to my website name and slogan.